# Inserting Hyperlinks into selected area in powerpoint

Tags: powerpoint, office-js

I have been trying to insert a Hyperlink in a Microsoft Powerpoint slide through a button click from Add-in Taskpane.

I have tried using the `setSelectedDataAsync(data, options, callback).`
But i am only able to insert Plain Text and Images through this method.

```
Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync('Hello World!',function (asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) 
    {
         console.log(asyncResult.error.message);
    }
});
```

Is there any way to insert a HyperLink or HTML in the selected area ?

Comment: What happens if you insert a URL as the `data` parameter? Does it stay a string in the slide or does PowerPoint autoconvert it to a link?

Comment: The URL stays as a string. It does not get converted to a link.

Comment: OK. Let's try another experiment. See if you can insert a TextBox shape with the URL string as the text value, using the PowerPoint-specific APIs. See [Shapes - TextBoxes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/powerpoint/shapes#text-boxes) for details. See if it automatically changes to a link.

Comment: The text doesn't get converted to link when i insert a TextBox shape with a URL link as the text value. The URL remains as a simple text.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not an answer for your need (office-js), but for anybody who would like to realize it in VBA:

```
Sub SetLinkOnActiveShape(strLink As String)
'Inserts a hyperlink on the selected shape(s)

Dim shp As Shape

'Determine if shape(s) is/are selected
  If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionShapes Then
    'Loop for each shape in selection
       For Each shp In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
            'Insert link on the shape
            With shp.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)
                .Action = ppActionHyperlink
                .Hyperlink.Address = strLink
            End With
       Next shp
  Else
    MsgBox "There is no shape currently selected!", vbExclamation, "No Shape Found"
    Exit Sub
  End If
    
End Sub


Sub testSetLink()

    SetLinkOnActiveShape "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74569639/inserting-hyperlinks-into-selected-area-in-powerpoint"

End Sub
```

(Combination of  https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/vba/2015/2/18/determine-the-current-activeshape-in-powerpoint-with-vba and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.hyperlink)